# How to Regex MultiVariables

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to regex this, but it doesnt work:

this is my string:

```
asdasd2-bgbegebr23-yiyity23-iopip123
```

So im trying to get: all values between '-', but it doesnt work: im using actually this:

```
/(-)(.*)(-)/gi
```

as regex, but doesnt work, thanks everyone :S

Comment: `(-)(.*?)(-)`........

Comment: How do you define "all values" - in your example do you want to get `bgbegebr23-yiyity23` or `bgbegebr23` and `yiyity23` or perhaps  `asdasd2`, `bgbegebr23`,  `yiyity23` and `iopip123`?

Comment: you could just use `string.split('delimiter')` if that's an option.  Much easier and clearer than regex

Comment: yes, it works, thank u dlkulp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the dot includes de dash. You should remove the dash. Try this:

/([^-]+)/gi

Comment: That's the simplest solution yes. However, it's equivalent to doing `str.split("-")` and that tends to be easier to process. Also, OP mentions he wants the matches _between_ dashes. I don't know his exact requirements but it might be that this returns more than what OP wanted (includes both the first and the last item).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand very well the purpose of your regex. Supposing that you want to desgin a regular expression that **iterated over** the example string gets succesively asdasd2, bgbegebr23, etc, the regular expression will be something like this:

```
\-?([^\-]*)\-?
```

**Why??**

1. - : You have to use "-" instead of "-" because the hyphen is a special char for regular expressions, so you have to escape it
2. ?  : The hyphen is optional: in the first case (asdasd2), it is not present. So, enforcing it will omit this first case.
3. () : Grouping to catch all the asdsas2 and that alphanumeric stuff..
4. [^-] : Everything except hyphen. The approximation of @vks (.*?) I think will work also
5. - : Again, a hyphen, but escaped. And we cannot forget the "?" at the end because the last case of the example string, which doesn't end in hyphen.

And don't forget that if you are working in javascript you might need to scape the backslash (), resulting in an expression like this:

```
\\-?[^\\-]*)\\-?
```

Comment: `the hyphen is a special char for regular expressions` no, it is not. not in those positions, anyway - it only is special inside `[]` and only if it can be interpreted as a range, e.g. `[0-9]`. However, outside the square brackets or _inside_ and at the beginning/end it will never be considered special.  `enforcing it will omit this first case` well, are you sure that's not what OP wants? As in, he might actually _want_ to omit the first case. `you might need to scape the backslash` not if you're using a regex literal. You do in strings, though but a literal will now be WRONG.

Comment: thanks you dude, i cant understand at all what means this -> hyphen., but thanks

Comment: Im using this: and doesnt work : var r = /([^-]+)/gi.exec( "intro-verse1-verse2-chorus1-intro-verse1-verse2-chorus1-chorus2-bridge-bridge-bridge-chorus1-chorus2-intro" )

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña try `string.match(/([^-]+)/g)` - this will give you all the words. It would be even simpler to do without regex, however: `string.split("-")`